# Why are the entities being eager-loaded?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lazy-loading, dbcontext

I have an entity hierarchy with several layers, one of which contains objects that can number in the 10s of thousands. There are occasions when I want only the top-level object but I'm finding that the Entity Framework is loading *everything* in the hierarchy.

I've even tried explicit lazy loading, to no avail.

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

    var daoDict = (from d in db.stt_dictionary
                   where d.id == dictionaryID && !d.deleted
                   select d).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

While debugging, if I step through this and then hover over `daoDict` I find that its collection properties (which are `virtual`) contain thousands of objects.

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fetching them using the debugger is going to load them.  The debugger isn't doing anything any different than regular code would.  It's calling the getter of the property, and doing that fetches the data.

Log the database queries that are actually executed (either through the context or through the database) to see what data is being pulled when in a way that doesn't actually *change* what queries are being executed.

Comment: I've already looked into the debugger being the cause. What I've done is to add logging, and log the count of one of the collections which I would expect to be `null`, and it isn't. Or is the act of calling `.Count` fetching the data?

Comment: @awj As I said, the act of getting the property fetches the data.  That's the whole premise of lazy loading.  If you want it to error when you call the property getter then *disable lazy loading* and it'll throw an exception when you call the getter of an unloaded property.

Comment: Aha, yes - I can see it in the query now. Thanks for your help.